# Illegal string offset 'type' error on Detube Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am receiving an error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'type' in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/detube/admin/panel.php on line 692

Here is the code:

```
 690      if(is_array($new_meta_value))
 691                $new_meta_value = array_filter($new_meta_value);
 692            elseif($field['type'] == 'password')
 693                $new_meta_value = md5($new_meta_vlue);
```

Comment: Obviously, there's no `'type'` in the `$field` array.

Comment: how to fix it rnevius ?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($field)`?

Comment: i am new at wordpress. i d,not know about it but i want to fix this problem.